# Rename and move files in local system using website

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, web-deployment

I am developing a website with frontend react and backend as django where users can generate names of files in a particular format. Now this files will be in their local system or their local servers we can say. I need to rename the file and move that to a source folder. Is that possible using a website? I have heard this is possible but now sure how. Anybody knows how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers accessing the local files system is considered as a security threat!

Imagine websites having the freedom to access all your files and images!

however for certain use-cases, this can be enabled on the browser itself, to enable websites from accessing file system.

however it is supported by google chrome only (as far as i know) you can use the [FileSystem.API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) you can check this here [Can i Use: FileSystem](https://caniuse.com/?search=filesystem)